# How do you iterate over a tree?

Tags: python, algorithm

What is your preferred method of traversing a tree data structure, since recursive method calls can be pretty inefficient in some circumstances. I am simply using a generator like the one above. Do you have any hints to make it faster?

```
def children(self):
    stack = [self.entities]
    while stack: 
        for e in stack.pop():
            yield e
            if e.entities:
                stack.append(e.entities)
```

Here is some test data.
The first one is recursive, the second uses the generator:

```
s = time.time()
for i in range(100000):
    e.inc_counter()
print time.time() - s

s = time.time()
for i in range(100000):
    for e in e.children():
        e.inc_counter_s()
print time.time() - s
```

Results:

```
0.416000127792
0.298999786377
```

Test code:

```
import random

class Entity():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.entities = []
        self.name = name
        self.counter = 1
        self.depth = 0

    def add_entity(self, e):
        e.depth = self.depth + 1
        self.entities.append(e)

    def inc_counter_r(self):
        for e in self.entities:
            e.counter += 1
            e.inc_counter_r()

    def children(self):
        stack = [self.entities]
        while stack:
            for e in stack.pop():
                yield e
                if e.entities:
                    stack.append(e.entities)

root = Entity("main")
def fill_node(root, max_depth):
    if root.depth <= max_depth:
        for i in range(random.randint(10, 15)):
            e = Entity("node_%s_%s" % (root.depth, i))
            root.add_entity(e)
            fill_node(e, max_depth)
fill_node(root, 3)

import time
s = time.time()
for i in range(100):
    root.inc_counter_r()
print "recursive:", time.time() - s

s = time.time()
for i in range(100):
    for e in root.children():
        e.counter += 1
print "generator:",  time.time() - s
```

Comment: uneffective? do you mean inefficient?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't think of any big algorithmic improvements, but a simple microoptimisation you can make is to bind frequently called methods (such as stack.append / stack.pop) to locals (this saves a dictionary lookup)

```
def children(self):
    stack = [self.entities]
    push = stack.append
    pop = stack.pop
    while stack: 
        for e in pop():
            yield e
            if e.entities:
                push(e.entities)
```

This gives a small (~15%) speedup by my tests (using 100 traversals of an 8-deep tree with 4 children at each node gives me the below timings:)

```
children     :  5.53942348004
children_bind:  4.77636131253
```

Not huge, but worth doing if speed is important.

Comment: I have to admid my former in application profiling results were sharper, maybe becouse of the tree structure or the methods called. But it is not insignificant either, also the ability to cache can lead to pretty interesting optimizations.

Answer (score 5):

Unless your tree is really large or you have really high (real) requirements for speed, I would choose the recursive method. Easier to read, easier to code.

Comment: I am actually traversing a scene graph of a 3D application, so the speed is an issue, but also these type of generators makes it easier to get the code in one place for different kind of objects, the code gets messier when you need filtering.

Answer (score 5):

Recursive function calls are not incredibly inefficient, that is an old programming myth. (If they're badly implemented, they may incur a larger overhead than necessary, but calling them "incredibly inefficient" is plain wrong.)

Remember: don't optimize prematurely, and *never* optimize without benchmarking first.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if you can reduce the overhead much on a *full* in-order traversal of a tree, if you use recursion the call stack will grow some, otherwise you must manually use a stack to push references of the children while visiting each node. Which way is fastest and uses less memory, depends on the expensiveness of the call stack vs. a normal stack. (I would guess the callstack is faster since it should be optimized for its use, and recursion is much easier to implement)

If you don't care about the order you visit the nodes, some implementations of trees is actually stored in a dynamic array or linked list or stack wich you can traverse linearly if you don't care about the order it's traversed.

But why is it important to have a fast traversal anyway? Trees are good for searching, arrays/linked lists is good for full traversal. If you often need full in-order traversal but few searches and insertions/deletions, an ordered linked list might be best, if searching is what you do most you use a tree. If the data is really massive, so that memory overhead may render recursion impossible, you should use a database.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a lot of RAM and the tree doesn't change often, you can cache the result of the call:

```
def children(self):
    if self._children_cache is not None:
        return self._children_cache
    # Put your code into collectChildren()
    self._children_cache = self.collectChildren()
    return self._children_cache
```

Whenever the tree changes, set the cache to None. In this case, using recursive calls might be more effective since the results will accumulate faster.

Comment: That is a good idea, also the generator can be changed to use the cache. if e has a children_cache than you iterate over the nodes instad of pushing it into stack. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've written iterative tree-traversal code in the past: it's very ugly, and not fast, unless you know *exactly* how many children not only each subtree will have, but how many levels there are.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know too much about Python internals of function calls, but I really can't imagine that your code snippet is faster than recursively traversing the tree.

The call stack (used for function calls, including recursive ones) is typically very fast. Going to the next object will only cost you a single function call. But in your snippet - where you use a stack object, going to the next object will cost you a stack.append (possibly allocating memory on heap), a stack.push (possibly freeing memory from heap), and a yield.

The main problem with recursive calls is that you might blow the stack if your tree gets too deep. This isn't likely to happen.

Comment: I have posted some simple test data.

Comment: Function calls are actually pretty expensive.  Each call must allocate a frame object (also on the heap), populate the parameters and then invoke it.  Compare doing that N times for N children vs a single append of N items and you'll see why the stack method is faster.

Comment: (continued) Yields are also much quicker than function calls, as they don't create new frames - the existing frame object is reused.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pair of small corrections.

```
def children(self):
    stack = [self.entities]
    for e in stack:
        yield e
        if e.entities:
            stack.extend(e.entities)
```

I actually think the generator, using append, isn't visiting all the nodes. I think you mean to `extend` the stack with all entities, not `append` a simple list of entities to the stack.

Also, when the `for` loop terminates, the `while` loop in your original example will also terminate because there's no change to the empty stack after the `for` loop.

Comment: Well, I did used a list of lists to prevent updating the list object I am interating over, I thought it is undefined to do that ?

Comment: You might be thinking of Java, where messing with the structure confuses the iterator.

Comment: ok, I have tested, it works, but it seems a little slower, becouse of the extend I suppose. 

recursive: 1.96200013161
generator: 1.68400001526
generator_new: 1.74000000954

Comment: At this point, it seems like you should close this question and start again with the corrected algorithms and current timing.  These times are more what I'd expect -- relatively minor differences.

Comment: Hello, as I mentioned in my comments, It changes bu the tree structure, I have used low max_depth in these tests, so difference is smaller. Besides, the topic also stands for caching, which is not possible using recursive way, we also did not discuss searching.

Comment: While I do not want to get into other sub topics, I think this question is still helpful to the others.

Comment: I'm not sure it's useful because your initial code sample (with append) and your initial times (based on append) are actually wrong.  That algorithm doesn't really work correctly.  I think posting a wrong algorithm like that is confusing and maybe a bad policy.